# XSLT interpreting tags with spaces as empty tags

Tags: xml, xslt, whitespace

I have an XSLT that is transformed to an XML using `System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform`. The problem is that tags with spaces are converted to empty tags. Below is a minimal sample to reproduce the problem.

Original data:

```
<data>
  <content>A</content>
  <content> </content>
  <content>B</content>
</data>
```

Output data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
  <content>A</content>
  <content />
  <content>B</content>
</data>
```

**The second tag is wrong! The space must not be eaten like that.**

And the **XSLT**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:preserve-space elements="content"/>
<xsl:template match="//data">
  <xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Is the XSLT wrong? Or should I blame the .NET XSL transformer (I've tried both 3.5 SP1 and 4.0)?

Please help!

Comment: You will have to add which xslt processor you are using (including the version). In your xslt the second template is not necessary as the first statement already copies the date element to the output. If you are using MSXML version 5 or earlier, you may have a problem with the whitespace handling as these processors have a known incompatibility there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As David pointed out the problem is that the spaces are stripped out before getting to the XSLT. The solution when using .NET is to use an `XmlReader` to read the input XML - this code should do the trick:

```
  XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
  transform.Load(@"c:\temp\space.xslt");
  using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(@"c:\temp\spaceSample.xml")) {
    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(@"c:\temp\space.xml")) {
      transform.Transform(reader, writer);
    }
  }
```

where `spaceSample.xml` in the input file, `space.xml` is the output and `space.xslt` is the transformation.

(Tested with .NET 4.0)

Comment: This approach does indeed produce the desired output for my simplified example. However, for my more complex data/xslt the spaces are still removed. I have to dig into this a bit more.

Answer (score 4):

You need to include (at top level):

```
<xsl:preserve-space elements="content"/>
```

If there are several node types that have to preserve spaces, list them in the `elements` attribute separated by blanks.  This is [documented here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#strip).

Comment: This is unlikely to make any difference, as the white space should be preserved anyway, so most likely the msxml parser is being used, in which case it will have removed the white space before XSLT gets a chance to preserve it.

Comment: The W3C spec is pretty clear about [whitespace stripping](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#strip).

Comment: Yes sure, and by the spec white space in the source is not stripped, this is a notorious non conformance issue with msxml. Since the parser removes it, it's gone from the input and xsl:preserve space does not preserve it. The spec is clear but msxml does not follow it.

Comment: This is a good idea, but it doesn't work. Using `System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Ah, I see. I've given your answer a +1.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using msxml it has a documented non conformance with respect to the xml spec and strips white space by default. You can either add `xml:space="preserve"` to your  element so that white space in that file is correctly handled, or if calling msxml via an API (but not if directly parsing xml in Internet Explorer) set its preserveWhitespace  property to true http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms766466%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Unrelated to the white space issue

```
<xsl:template match="//data/content">
  <xsl:element name="{title}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//data/content"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

is never executed, as the template matching `data` just copies the entire document, without applying templates recursively. If it *were* executed it would loop infinitely as it says, for each content element, apply templates to every content element.

UPDATE
If you don't need to preserve the exact white space, just putting a space in to make it non-empty then you can correct for the broken parsing by putting space back in the stylesheet, first fix things so templates are recursively applied, then have an extra template for empty content elements, making them non empty by adding a space.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="content[not(node())]">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
   <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that I'm using `System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform`. Adding `xml:space="preserve"` to the element is not desirable since this xml comes from another system. A workaround would be to replace all `data` tags with its spaced equivalent. Nice... :(

Comment: If you know that `<content>` should never be empty, and you don't care exactly what space is in there you can get the xslt to correct things by having a template that fixes it up, I'll add a note to my answer

Comment: This is also a good idea. Still, when used for my complex data/xslt, the result is still wrong. I will have to update my question with relevant data. Thanks for your tip though!